# How do I annotate the final value of a cumulative vector in a ggplot linechart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot line chart that shows two cumulative vectors of scores in a game (one for every team). Now I'm happy with the way it looks at the moment, but I would like to annotate the current score of a team at the end of the line (so the cumulative value).

The course of scores for the teams looks like this:

```
> testVectorJG
 [1]  17 138  45   0 182 117  49   0  94   0  57   0
> testVectorJW
 [1] 145  64 157 182   0  65 133 182 136 202 105 202
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
test_df <- tribble(~puntenvector, ~Team, ~Rondenummer, ~cumPunten,
                   145, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 1, 145,
                   64, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 2, 209,
                   157, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 3, 366,
                   182, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 4, 548,
                   0, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 5, 548,
                   65, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 6, 613,
                   133, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 7, 746,
                   182, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 8, 928,
                   136, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 9, 1064,
                   202, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 10, 1266,
                   105, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 11, 1371,
                   202, 'Jaap, &, Wil', 12, 1573,
                   17, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 1, 17,
                   138, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 2, 155,
                   45, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 3, 200,
                   0, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 4, 200,
                   182, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 5, 382,
                   117, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 6, 499,
                   49, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 7, 548,
                   0, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 8, 548,
                   94, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 9, 642,
                   0, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 10, 642,
                   57, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 11, 699,
                   0, 'Jasper, &, Gijs', 12, 699)
```

I am creating my current ggplot as follows:

```
ggplot(test_df, aes(x = Rondenummer, y = cumPunten, colour = Team, group = Team)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(y = "Punten",
         title = "Cumulatief aantal punten (inclusief roem) per ronde") +
    theme_grey()
```

So how can I display the current score of each team in a nice, non-overlapping way for both the teams at the end of the line?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2):

You can include a geom_text layer which plots only a subset of the data (that corresponding to the max round played so far). You can accomplish that by passing a subsetting function to that layer's `data` argument.

Also, for the no-overlapping thing, you can play a little with `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`. In this example, I only added a nudge_y.
Another option would be to use `geom_text_repel`, from the `ggrepel` package, which handles the non-overlapping thing for you.

```
max_round <- max(test_df$Rondenummer)
ggplot(test_df, aes(x = Rondenummer, y = cumPunten, colour = Team, group = Team)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = function(x) subset(x, Rondenummer == max_round),
            aes(label = cumPunten),
            nudge_x = 0.75) +
  labs(y = "Punten",
       title = "Cumulatief aantal punten (inclusief roem) per ronde") +
  theme_grey()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

ggrepel solution:

```
max_round <- max(test_df$Rondenummer)
ggplot(test_df, aes(x = Rondenummer, y = cumPunten, colour = Team, group = Team)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(data = function(x) subset(x, Rondenummer == max_round),
            aes(label = cumPunten)) +
  labs(y = "Punten",
       title = "Cumulatief aantal punten (inclusief roem) per ronde") +
  theme_grey()
```

[image: ggrepel]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a few problems though; The round numbers (so 1 to 12) are actually factor levels, so the `max()`-function doesn't work on them. I am okay with hardcoding the number 12 in there though. My second problem is that when I try to put the 12 in the place of your `max_round` the values halfway disappear on the side of the plot: I see, instead of your plot, only "15" for the first team. Also, when the two lines are close to each other, wouldn't these annotations overlap with each other?

Comment: The rounds can be factors, but since they have an intrinsic order to it's levels (and you are interested in that property, since you care about the most recent one), you should make them an ordered factor variable. After you do that, you will be able to get the max().
Yes, they might overlap if their cumPunten is too close. And the numbers might be going of the chart, since I nudged to the right. You could nudge in another direction, or use ggrepel.
I edited my answer to also include the code of the ggrepel solution.

Comment: By the way, I had edited your question before reading your comment, so that test_df was given as a reproducible example. In my edition I set Rondenummer as Numeric instead of Factor, sorry. In the future, please try to include a reproducible example yourself, to allow for quicker and better quality answers :)